# Show the reason for closing on the reopen votes page

Tags: support

When you review closed issues for reopening you get this information:

> This question was edited after it was closed. Should it be reopened?

But it says nothing about why it was closed.

Is there a reason for this?

I feel like it would be useful to have that information available on that page, do others agree?

Comment: +1 I agree, really it is difficult to guess the reason for the closer!.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That information is already there: Click on the "Question (revised)" tab; you will see the question in its current state, including the closing reason.

> [image: screenshot]